# make's foreach and specifying libraries to link against (-l)

Tags: makefile

In a Makefile, I have a list of libraries I have to link against:

```
LIBS=var.a foo.a
```

I want to run the following command (simplified):

```
$(CC) main.c -lvar.a -lfoo.a
```

Now I use:

```
$(CC) main.c $(foreach lib,$(LIBS),-l$(lib))
```

It works, however it looks a bit wordy/cumbersome. Is there any better way to do it? Another approach?

Thanks!

Comment: `$(addprefix -l,$(LIBS))`

Comment: I knew there must be something better. If you write it as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible improvement is to use the `addprefix` function.

```
$(addprefix -l,$(LIBS)
```

One could also use `patsubst`

```
$(patsubst %,-l%,$(LIBS))
```